# WHERE NOT EQUAL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-null

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select s.conclusion, t.* from trip t 
JOIN triprequirementsmapping m ON m.tripid = t.trip_id
JOIN approvalsubmission s ON s.requested = m.corporatetravelrequesturi
where s.conclusion <> 'DISCONTINUED'
```

The value of the `s.conclusion` is null for this example.

**Problem**

This query returns no rows, when I expect it to return one row, because `s.conclusion` is not `DISCONTINUED`.

**Question**

How do I do the WHERE clause to return all rows that don't have a value of `DISCONTINUED`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly deal with the NULL value:

```
where s.conclusion <> 'DISCONTINUED' or s.conclusion IS NULL
```

Postgres offers a useful operator for that situation which deals with NULL values as expected.

```
where s.conclusion is distinct from 'DISCONTINUED'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer. I will mark it when the time allows